# VB.NET, Call an executable with parameter by a macro

Tags: vb.net, macros, executable, parameters

I have an application that used Macro.

In this macro I would like to call an external executable like this:

```
SYSTEM( "C:\Programme\Transform.exe" , 
        "C:\Programme\Vectors.txt" , 
        "C:\Programme\Vectors_Compensate.txt", 
        "C:\Programme\Vectors_Final.txt" )
```

This executable reconstruct a modified file according to a template file. 
Finally, a new file is create.

Transform.exe open a form that ask the Path for
- Template File
- Modified file
- where you want to put the new reconstruct file.

After this you press start.

I would like that when you call that command line

```
SYSTEM( "C:\Programme\Transform.exe" , 
        "C:\Programme\Vectors.txt" , 
        "C:\Programme\Vectors_Compensate.txt", 
        "C:\Programme\Vectors_Final.txt" )
```

The parameter will go in the place in the form.

How can I do that ???

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the environment you're using from your question. Are you writing a macro or using a macro from some other language or application? What application or environment are you using that supports and executes macros? What language is the macro written in (is it VB.NET or something else?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enter code here`I found it :

```
 Dim cmdLine As String
            Dim Parms() As String ' if the paramters are strings - declare this as necessary
            cmdLine = Command$()  ' Command$ would return "Parms1 Parms2 Parms3"

            Parms = Split(cmdLine, " ")

            'This section filled the form textbox.
            TextBoxTemplate.Text = Parms(0)
            TextBoxModify.Text = Parms(1)
            TextBoxFinal.Text = Parms(2)
```